# cannot use custom message

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a custom message file.
I have done the necessary modifications in CMakeLists.txt.  and I have run `catkin build`

So now when I do `rosmsg list` I can clearly see my custom message

```
roscustom_test/TheObject
```

also when I do this:  `rosmsg show TheObject` I can clearly see

```
[roscustom_test/TheObject]
....components
```

However when I try to use it from a script.py I do

```
from roscustom_test.msg import TheObject
```

I get

```
from roscustom_test.msg import TheObject 
Import Error: No module named roscustom_test.msg
```

What am I doing wrong here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372198/cannot-use-custom-message/) by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2021-02-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never mind. I found out that after catkin build I should source devel/setup.bash again

---

Originally posted by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) with karma: 170 on 2021-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1